# Select last value in a specific column? (PostgreSQL)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Running into some issues when trying to retrieve the last value in a specific column,  from a table and assign it into a variable.

Looking for the last int  in a column "id"  that is a primary key basically.

So I have a variable like "lastValue" in a select statement like :

select last(id) into lastValue from test_table

Not sure on an exact,  or best way to accomplish this.

(on mobile,  please forgive formatting)

Comment: if id's are ordered ascending you could use "max"

Comment: You want `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A typical way to solve this is with `order by` and `limit`:

```
select id
from test_table
order by id desc
limit 1;
```

Of course, in this case, you could simply use:

```
select max(id)
from test_table;
```

But the first method allows you to choose whichever variables you want from the row with the maximum value.

Comment: Thanks Gordon,  I'll give the first method a go,  I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.